# Boolean algebra 2 different simplification?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

**Wondering why the following boolean expression seem to have 2 possible simplification? Are these two both correct ? Thank you very much !**

[How online tutorial solves it:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKiTfSWl130) 
[image]

**How I simplify it**

[image]

**How online tool sovles it** <--- Same as my answer
[image]

Comment: Yes, there may be different ways to simply a boolean term. Both ways are correct. You can create a truth table for all three terms (ie the initial term and both simplifications) you will see, that they are equal ...

Comment: Do you understand/know Karnaugh maps?

Comment: Thanks, I drew the truth table and found they are the same.
I know K-map , but not very familiar yet, will check soon, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) you will see that they are the same. See the following Karnaugh map for this boolean expression, almost completely matched with circles:

[image: KV map partially filled]

The blue circle matches the expression `BC`, the red circle matches the expression `B'C'`. The remaining cell at `AB'C` still needs a circle. There are three ways to create a circle, which matches this cell:

[image: KV map completely filled solution 1.)]

In this solution, the cell `AB'C` is matched by a circle with only one cell. However this is not the biggest circle possible in this Karnaugh map. The circles chosen in a Karnaugh map are picked to be the biggest circle possible (according to the Karnaugh map rules).

The "real" other solutions are:

[image: KV map completely with left circle]

The green circle in this solution matches `AC`. The remaining third solution is this one:

[image: KV map completely with right circle]

The green circle in this solution matches `AB'`.

This means that all these three boolean expressions are equal:

- `BC + B'C' + AB'C` *(can still be more simplified, shows what happens when too small circles are choose in Karnaugh maps)*
- `BC + B'C' + AC`  *(your solution)*
- `BC + B'C' + AB'` *(solution from the video)*

Comment: Your first expression can be further simplified (giving the second one) with the absorption law. Ie `BC + B'C' + AB'C` = `B'C' + C(B + AB')` = `B'C' + C(A + B)` = `B'C' + AC + BC)`. And this also meets a basic principle of KV diagrams, ie making the circles as big as possible, so you can remove parts like `CC'` from the terms.